# ARCamera.projectPoint swift implementation

Tags: ios, swift, render, linear-algebra, arkit

I am trying to implement an ARCamera.projectPoint function using projectionMatrix and viewMatrix from the camera.

Going to create something like this:

```swift
let position = simd_float3(x: 1, y: 2, z: 3)
let position4 = simd_float4(x: position.x, y: position.y, z: position.z, w: 1)

let projectionMatrix = frame.camera.projectionMatrix(for: .landscapeRight, viewportSize: frame.camera.imageResolution, zNear: 0.001, zFar: 1000.0)
let viewMatrix = frame.camera.viewMatrix(for: .landscapeRight)

let projection = position4 * projectionMatrix * viewMatrix
let arkitProjection = frame.camera.projectPoint(position, orientation: .landscapeRight, viewportSize: frame.camera.imageResolution)

assert(projection.x == Float(arkitProjection.x))
assert(projection.y == Float(arkitProjection.y))
```

But I don't know how to implement it correctly. Hope for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close! What you have in `projection` is actually a "clip space" position (also note I fixed the order of the matrix multiplication). You then need to convert that to a "normalized device coordinate" (which has coordinates from -1 to +1 in xyz dimensions) using "perspective divide". Then finally you need to linear map it to the position in the image based on the image size.

```swift
let position = simd_float3(x: 1, y: 2, z: 3)
let position4 = simd_float4(x: position.x, y: position.y, z: position.z, w: 1)

let projectionMatrix = frame.camera.projectionMatrix(for: .landscapeRight, viewportSize: frame.camera.imageResolution, zNear: 0.001, zFar: 1000.0)
let viewMatrix = frame.camera.viewMatrix(for: .landscapeRight)

let clipSpacePosition = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * position4
let normalizedDeviceCoordinate = clipSpacePosition / clipSpacePosition.w
let projection = CGPoint(
    x: (CGFloat(normalizedDeviceCoordinate.x) + 1) * (frame.camera.imageResolution.width / CGFloat(2)),
    y: ((-CGFloat(normalizedDeviceCoordinate.y) + 1)) * (frame.camera.imageResolution.height / CGFloat(2))
)

let arkitProjection = frame.camera.projectPoint(position, orientation: .landscapeRight, viewportSize: frame.camera.imageResolution)

assert(abs(projection.x - arkitProjection.x) < 0.01)
assert(abs(projection.y - arkitProjection.y) < 0.01)
```

Further reading:

- http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/#the-projection-matrix (generally useful info about clip space and projection)
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/tracking_and_visualizing_faces (search "perspective divide")
- https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems